# React updating Switch controller State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have multiples Switch elements and I'm trying to have a object state to control the state of the switches: true or false.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch } from '@material-ui/core';

const Test = () => {
   const [ notifications, setNotifications ] = useState({
        transactionModification: false,
        missedPromissPay: false,
        chargesPosted: false,
        productUpdate: false
    })

    return (
       <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-2">
                <FormGroup check className="mb-20">
                    <Label for="transactionModification" className="mr-sm-10">Transaction Modifications</Label>
                    <Switch name="transactionModification" checked={notifications.transactionModification} 
                        onChange={(prevState) => setNotifications({...prevState, transactionModification: !prevState.transactionModification})} />
                </FormGroup>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2">
                <FormGroup check className="mb-20">
                    <Label for="missedPromissPay" className="mr-sm-10">Missed Promise to Pay</Label>
                    <Switch name="missedPromissPay" checked={notifications.missedPromissPay} 
                        onChange={(prevState) => setNotifications({...prevState, missedPromissPay: !prevState.missedPromissPay})} />
                </FormGroup>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2">
                <FormGroup check className="mb-20">
                    <Label for="chargesPosted" className="mr-sm-10">Charges Posted</Label>
                    <Switch name="chargesPosted" checked={notifications.chargesPosted} 
                        onChange={(prevState) => setNotifications({...prevState, chargesPosted: !prevState.chargesPosted})} />
                </FormGroup>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2">
                <FormGroup check className="mb-20">
                    <Label for="productUpdateNotifications" className="mr-sm-10">Product Update Notifications</Label>
                    <Switch name="productUpdateNotifications" checked={notifications.productUpdate} 
                        onChange={(prevState) => setNotifications({...prevState, productUpdate: !prevState.productUpdate})} />
                </FormGroup>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

The issue is that when I check one Switch and then go check another one, the first one checked changes its value. Why is it happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the functional update wrong. This is the right way:

```
onChange={() => setNotifications((prevState)=>{...prevState, chargesPosted: !prevState.chargesPosted})}
```

You have to add a callback to the setState. The way you did it, prevState will be the event.